# Display dynamic googleVis output in a members only Wordpress blog

Tags: wordpress, r, google-visualization

I am creating a subscription based Wordpress blog and will be looking to display R googleVis output (as HTML) that will update about every 30 minutes.  There are already a couple questions/answers on how to display R googleVis output in Wordpress, but they rely on either:

1. manually pasting the html into an individual post, or
2. writing the output.html file to a web server and referencing the URL in an inline frame within the blog.

The first option will not work for me since the content is updated every 30 minutes, and the second option would allow nonmembers to circumvent Wordpress security by navigating directly to the URL for the inline frame.  Any ideas on how I could post this content through Wordpress while still maintaining subscriber only access would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could use [WordPess APIs](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Support) to update the post with new HTML. For example, [wp.editPost](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_WordPress_API/Posts#wp.editPost).

Comment: @nandhp is correct, you can use the RWordpress package to update your site via a script chron'd on the server. Useful example here: http://wkmor1.wordpress.com/2012/07/01/rchievement-of-the-day-3-bloggin-from-r-14/

Comment: This is an interesting idea.  I am experimenting with it but it will take me some time to definitively say if it works.  R/googleVis is outputting a .html file (in its whole).  I will have to get the api to overwrite everything pre-existing, but the real issue is getting the api  to write in a way that WP can actually process the Javascript. (GoogleVis has issues with WP).  I will continue to work on it and update accordingly.

Comment: It appears that RWordpress (nor any of its suspected capitalization deviations) is available for download/installation through console.  The site where it is supposedly hosted pending google search also has a broken link where the download should be. It also looks like there's a related project on github (just google it) but there is no .tar.gz file for install. Please let me know if there is another place to get the download.

Comment: Anyone else have any ideas?

Comment: To download RWordpress you can use `install.packages("RWordPress", repos = "http://www.omegahat.org/R")`

Comment: Also, the visual editor breaks things (so does clicking back and forth between it and the html editor in Wordpress). Disable the visual editor and try doing it again.